# Blinking contour line

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, video-processing, contour

[My program's objective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706163/problems-with-finding-contour-in-a-video-image-using-c-findcontours) is to identify the largest contour from a video camera and draw it with red line.

I discovered that when the largest contour (aka `largest_contours` in my program) is detected, the contour's contour line will blink and <strike>sometime</strike> will interrupt the function to draw a red line around it (because the contour's line is not connected anymore so no more contour detected inside the image).

My questions are:

1. What is the reason for this problem to happen?
2. How to avoid (or can we avoid) this problem from happening?
3. Any suggestions to improve my contour's detection program?

Thanks in advance.

PS: For the codes, pics and more info, click [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706163/problems-with-finding-contour-in-a-video-image-using-c-findcontours). [VIDEO HERE!!!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GLabxxd228&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: The "blinking" problem is very likely caused by noise/lighting, yes, but this is also a probable indication that you are not using any other previous frames you have. You might want to average frames, followed by the typical suggestions with this method. But, to give any accurate help you have to include some short sample videos of your own that have the problems you describe.

Comment: Video added. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GLabxxd228&feature=youtu.be

Comment: That is a video of your application running, no one needs that. What is needed are your original frames, check `VideoWriter` for that.

Answer (score 0):

`findContours` API of OpenCV modifies the image which it uses to find contours.You can try the following.

```
Mat displayContours = Mat::zeros(image.rows,image.cols,CV_8UC1);
for(int i = 1;i<(int)largest_contours[0].size();i++)
{
   line(displayContours,largest_contours[0][i-1],largest_contours[0][i],255,2,8,0);
   line(image,largest_contours[0][i-1],largest_contours[0][i],cv::Scalar(0,0,255),2,8,0);
}
```

Now display the `displayContours` instead of `foreground`